# Required field validation on textbox

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

```
          try
        {
            Connections.con.Open();
            string str = "INSERT INTO `Employee` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `DOB`, `ContactNumber`, `Username`, `Password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, Connections.con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtFirst.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtLast.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtDOB.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtCon.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtUser.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtPass.Text.ToString());


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Registration Successful");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username Exists.");
        }
        finally
        {

            Connections.con.Close();
            this.Dispose();
            this.Close();
            f1.Show();
        }
```

I can't find a way that the form will prompt a message that says Please fill up the empty field..
whenever the user forgot to fill the text box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the backend code you could just validate the values from the text box as follow:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirst.Text))
{
    // return required field message 
}
```

However, I would also add validation on the frontend using jQuery.Validation or similar: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

By the way, try enclosing your data persistence code with a "using" statement, it takes care of closing the connection and disposing of it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Required Field Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `TextBox`:

Example Code:

```
   <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server"/>

   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
        ErrorMessage="Required"
        runat="server"/>
```

It will not **PostBack** until the user fills the `Textbox`, and will show the message `Required` (You can change it by setting ErrorMessage="YourMessage") right after the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Create CheckTextBoxes as function which return boolean value and in which you can check for those textboxes that are empty:

```
if (TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0) 
{
    MessageBox.Show ("Your Message");
    return false;
}
```

Similarly, you can check multiple textboxes in this function and if any textbox is empty just return false and so you dont need to execute your **TRY** part

And your Try will look like below:

```
try
{
if(CheckTextBoxes() == true)
{
  // Your code

}
```